# How to drag and drop Rows from Grid view to Grid view

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='tbplayers']/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]")).click();   
WebElement dragme = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='tbplayers']/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]"));
WebElement drop = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='tbField']/tbody/tr/td"));
Actions action =new Actions(driver);
Action dragAndDrop = action.clickAndHold(dragme).moveToElement(drop).release(drop).build();
dragAndDrop.perform();
```

While executing the test script, I am not able to drop the row values and I am not getting any error message.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is not required to use both `Action` and `Actions` classes. `Actions` is part of selenium and you should use it:

```
Actions actions =new Actions(driver);
actions.clickAndHold(dragme).moveToElement(drop).release(drop).build().perform();
```

It should work.

Or you can simply use built-in method:

```
Actions actions =new Actions(driver);
actions.dragAndDrop(dragme, drop).build().perform();
```